# turtle-graphics: Using if-else statement to determine turtle parameters

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

I have an if-else statement that I am using to determine the turtle's pen color and line width. When I run my program, it will plot the appropriate points, but only draw them in 'white' with the minimum line width. Within the 'windspeeds' list, there are numerous values that exceed the minimum standard of 74 in my if-else statement. What causes the if-statement to not pass the value into the correct statement?

```
t.penup()
t.setpos(longitudes[0], latitudes[0])
t.pendown()
i = 0
while i < len(latitudes):
    t.setpos(longitudes[i], latitudes[i])
    for index in windspeeds:
        if index < 74:
            t.pencolor("white")
            t.width(2)
        elif 74 <= index <= 95:
            t.pencolor("blue")
            t.width(4)
        elif 96 <= index <= 110:
            t.pencolor("green")
            t.width(6)
        elif 111 <= index <= 129:
            t.pencolor("yellow")
            t.width(8)
        elif 130 <= index <= 156:
            t.pencolor("#FFA500")
            t.width(10)
        elif 157 <= index:
            t.pencolor("red")
            t.width(12)
    i += 1
```

Comment: please add demodata for `windspeed`, `latitude`, `longitude` - why index and not `speed` as running var for windspeeds? Also - why carrying the lower bound around for the `elif`'s ... if its < 74 the `if` would have matched already - so the next only needs `elif index <= 95:` .. etc

Comment: After setting the turtle's color and width the code in your question doesn't move it and draw anything...it just loops again and changes them to something else without ever utilizing them.

Comment: Thank you, I see it, and thanks for the code redundancy check too @Patrick Artner

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're iterating through all of `windspeeds` for each point, but you're not moving the pen. The last element in `windspeeds` is likely less than 74.

So for each position you're going through all the windspeeds, changing the color and width multiple times without moving the pen. So after moving the pen, you always end up back with `t.pencolor("white")` and `t.width(2)`.

Is the `windspeeds` array supposed to be indexed like the `longitudes` and `latitudes` arrays? If so you probably want something like:

```
t.penup()
t.setpos(longitudes[0], latitudes[0])
t.pendown()
for i in range(len(latitudes)):
    t.setpos(longitudes[i], latitudes[i])
    speed = windspeeds[i]
    if speed < 74:
        t.pencolor("white")
        t.width(2)
    elif speed < 94:
        t.pencolor("blue")
        t.width(4)
...
    elif speed < 157:
        t.pencolor("#FFA500")
        t.width(10)
    else:
        t.pencolor("red")
        t.width(12)
```

Comment: Yes, they are indexed the same. I see what you're saying about **when** the movement of the pen occurs. I was thinking that logic was occurring out of the loop (i.e. once the color changed, it stayed changed, so as long as it got changed int he first place it was okay.) But I can see how when scope is considered, that's not the case. Thanks for your clarification.